# Sip configuration for Elastix, for Terrasip (Provider) with Multiple DIDs

Tags: asterisk, sip, pbx, freepbx

I have just purchased several DIDs with [Terrasip](http://terrasip.com) I have configured my Elastix (freepbx) SIP trunk according to their suggestion:

```
Please follow this template configuration. (valid for outbound/inbound traffic)

Outgoing trunk name ***terrasip***

username=***sip_key***
type=friend
secret=***password***
host=terrasip.net
fromuser=***sip_key**
context=from-pstn ;(or set which is your inbound context) allow=g729,ulaw,alaw
trustrpid=yes
sendrpid=yes
canreinvite=no
insecure=very

;Add the follow line:
; register the user in order to receive inbound call for your sipkey

Registration String:
***sip_key***:***password***@terrasip.net/***sip_key***

Where ***sip_key*** - customer sipkey account
and***password*** - customer password
```

Outbound calls work, and so do inbound, but I can't route DIDs to multiple IVRs since all calls are received with the following context: ***sip_key***@from-trunk:1

I tried mapping the route from terrasip to ***DID_NUMBER***@mypbxserver.com
but when I dial, nothing arrives at my pbx.

I have already googled and found [This Solution](http://elastix.org/index.php/component/kunena/20-elastix-community-/86396-issues-with-wrong-did-number-on-incoming-calls.html?lang=en#87647) it proved faulty as even after the custom-inbound processing my DID is somehow the SIPKEY.

I have contacted their support and yet to get a reply, I will hopefully update with their reply, but in the meenwhile I would like my phone to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was eventually resolved (after much tcpdump, nc and support tickets)
Firewall was the issue for as why terrasip wouldn't send calls to my PBX (although properly registered and allowed for all of their range)

For direct mapping with Terrasip you must allow their *Gateway*'s IP address.

IP : 195.20.217.64
Secondary IPs : 81.201.82.45,81.201.83.45

Hope this ever helps anyone,
thanks for participating.